How to use SVF2 model version from BIM360?
I am currently using models from BIM360 and have noticed a significant difference in loading times between the BIM360 viewer and my APS Viewer.
Upon investigation, I discovered that BIM360 is utilizing SVF2, whereas my APS Viewer is using SVF (confirmed with NOP_VIEWER.model.isSVF2() on both viewers).
Looking at the derivatives in the manifest gives:
...
   "extractorVersion": "2026.6.6.1636",
   "outputType": "svf",
   "overrideOutputType": "svf2",
...

Some older blogs mention that we should use different viewer options:
 var options = {
    env:"MD20ProdUS",
    api: "D3S",
    ...
 }

But it does not work (the viewer crashes on initialization) and is not necessary since v7.48.
Is there any way to use the SVF2 version of BIM360 / ACC files from the automatic conversion without doing any other translation ?

From documentation:
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'AutodeskProduction2', api: 'streamingV2', getAccessToken }, function () {
   const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container, { extensions });
   viewer.start();
});

In case of EU region:
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'AutodeskProduction2', api: 'streamingV2_EU', getAccessToken }, function () {
   const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container, { extensions });
   viewer.start();
});


Thank you @varunpatil, I missed that part. However, when I change from derivativeV2 to streamingV2, my viewer is not working anymore. I get a 400 (Bad request) error from xhr.js

Can you add more details about the error? And how do you get the derivative urn? Do you get it from a version of version.relationships.derivatives.data.id ? Just tested, the model can be loaded good with the suggested code at my side.

Also make sure the model in ACC or BIM360 is translated to SVF2 correctly..

I am using the APS Hubs Browser Nodejs and I only replaced env and api with the suggested valuess for SVF2. As explained in my question, I assume that the default ACC/BIM360 translation to SVF2 is correct (as it's working with SVF2 on ACC/BIM360 viewers)

I found the solution. My problem was related to the way I get the derivative urn. As I was using the Hubs browser example with the tree, the urn came from the version id instead of using version.relationships.derivatives.data.id. Thank you for your help
